# Is it possible to insert a gif in latex (Overleaf)?

Tags: latex, gif, pdflatex

I'm writing a latex file on Overleaf and I would insert a gif image.
Is it possible? Because I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a gif/animation onto Beamer (post Adobe retiring Flash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718338/how-to-add-a-gif-animation-onto-beamer-post-adobe-retiring-flash)

Comment: No, it isn't @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: The  please add more information why the described workaround does not work for you. You can't include .gif directly, such a workaround is the best we can offer

Comment: I tried using the solution of the question you mentioned above, but it doesn't work, even if the document class is beamer. So other options?

Comment: "Does not work" is not a really helpful error description. Did you view the pdf in adobe reader in presentation mode?

Comment: does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492401/how-to-add-gif-file-to-overleaf) help?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by converting the `gif` to a set of `png`s and then using the [animate](https://texblog.org/2018/03/05/the-animate-package/) package.

For the first task you can exploit one of the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492493/258324).

Once you have a series of image files named with a shared prefix (e.g. `fig-`) and an increasing index that track the order in which they have to appear, then the usage of `animate} is pretty simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, animate}


\title{animate SO}
\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}

This is how to insert gif in main document:

% use the usual figure environment and substitute \includegraphics with \animategraphics
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    % \includegraphics{}
     \animategraphics[width=\textwidth, loop, autoplay]{1}%frame rate
    {figures/fig-}%path to figures
    {1}%start index
    {4}%end index
    \caption{Local gif}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Notice that I needed to express the path to the location of the figures as`./figures/<fig-prefix>` in case the `\animategraphics` is called by an external *tex* file which is included in the main.
I created a sample overleaf [project](https://www.overleaf.com/7827426966cxrzffnppvyw) to showcase the usage.

Finally, I'd suggest have a look to [StackExchange LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for latex related question :)